# remix scam, did i get scammed?

Tags: remix, ether, web3-providers, scam

I made a smart contact without looking into it much, but here is the video and code
video: `https://youtu.be/BvIpfcKzwbk`
Code: https://pastebin.com/raw/xCBDQc3V

Im unable to withdraw anything now, i've seen other people with similar issues but the money remains in the smart contract for months so thats strange

Comment: Yes, you were scammed. That scam contract has been around for 2 o 3 years. Video and comments are fake.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think it seems likely...

Haven't watched the whole video but as the official remix website warns, the only URL Remix uses is https://remix.ethereum.org/, but this youtube provides a different one.